# OpenCV GPU Mat Hanging

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I think I have an interesting issue here and would love to get some help.

**Hardware**

2x Identical Machines

- i-7 4770
- Asus Mobo
- 8GB of ram
- GTX 750 (Maxwell) (driver version 335.23)

**Software**

- VS2010
- VS2012
- OpenCV 2.4.5 (compiled on Kepler hardware)
- Cuda 5.0

As the title says, when I try to create an OpenCV `GpuMat` (`cv::gpu::Gpumat`), the program will "hang." What I mean by this is that no further executions will occur. What makes this interesting is that CUDA installed successfully, the OpenCV headers were compiled using CMake and have been verified on other computers (and `gpu::setDevice()` does not return an error on the current machine), and the program will occasionally run. The code below is what I am testing with.

In the below implementation, the code will hang at `gpuMat_1.upload(cpuMat_1)`. Previously (when tested as a benchmark to make sure that certain parts were working), `gpuMat.upload` would complete. After confirming that on two identical machines (each with a GTX 750) both were brought up to having 2 uploads and one add (currently displayed) and will not finish the first upload. When the second upload is removed, and the add with it, it still hangs during the first upload.

Thank you for your help. If there is anything else that I should add, or would help clarify the problem, please ask.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\gpu\gpu.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Number of gpu devices: " << cv::gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() << std::endl;

    cv::Mat cpuMat_1, cpuMat_2;
    cv::gpu::GpuMat gpuMat_1, gpuMat_2, gpuMat_3;

    cpuMat_1 = cv::Mat::ones(4, 4, CV_8SC1);
    cpuMat_2 = cv::Mat::ones(4, 4, CV_8SC1);

    gpuMat_1.upload(cpuMat_1);
    std::cout << "Help." << std::endl;
    gpuMat_2.upload(cpuMat_2);
    std::cout << "Please, help." << std::endl;

    cv::gpu::add(gpuMat_1, gpuMat_2, gpuMat_3);

    std::cout << "Help has come." << std::endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Update: I recently re-compiled OpenCV on one of these units (to account for hardware changes) and am getting the same issues.

Comment: 335.23. I will add it now, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: You should have `.pdb` files for OpenCV libraries, try running this in a debugger and use break/breakpoints and step into/over to find out what it does before/when it hangs. Is it going into some kind of loop, hangs on a CUDA call, etc. This should probably help diagnosing the issue.

Comment: In the current implementation (code above), I added a breakpoint at gpuMat_1.upload and with "Show next statement" I was not presented with anything, and "Step Into" causes it to hang. Earlier I changed the GpuMat initialization to a pointer and it would go into the constructor, only to hang when "create" is called. Edit: grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be an incompatibility with OpenCV 2.4.5 and the new Maxwell architecture. I was able to get my hands onto a Quadro 600 and installed that to test it, and it worked fine. I then tested it with a GTX 650, which also worked. I then tested it using the mog2 motion detection libraries on the 650, which also work.

Comment: Do you know if OpenCV 2.4.9 is compatible with the Maxwell architecture?  I just bought a GeForce 750 Ti for use with OpenCV!! Wish I had read this a few weeks ago.

Comment: I can't answer that for sure right now. We will be updating all our libraries eventually, but there is no telling when. If you do test it, please let me know.

Comment: Got it working.  As it turns out, the Maxwell uses has a new architecture 50.  Take a look at: http://docs.nvidia.com/maxwell-compatibility-guide.  Just have to set CUDA_ARCH_BIN to 1.1 2.0 3.0 3.5 5.0  and also set CUDA_ARCH_PTX to 5.0  This tells NVCC to create binary code (ready to run) for the 1.1-5.0 architectures and also to create PTX (JIT compiled) for 5.0 so that if you write any 5.0 specific code, its backward compatible to the other architectures.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Those settings (CUDA_ARCH_PTX and CUDA_ARCH_BIN) are in CMake...in case that isn't clear.  :-)

Comment: Awesome, I remember checking them but didn't get the same results...I will try again soon and test. It could have just been I forgot one of the boxes, as I was going based on what my coworker had originally told me.

Comment: Bryan Greenway, I have GTX 750 Maxwell architecture and wasn't able to build OpenCV with CUDA even when setting CUDA_ARCH_BIN to 1.1 2.0 3.0 3.5 5.0 and CUDA_ARCH_PTX to 5.0.

I will try with a different GPU...