# gpu::cvtColor(input_gpu, output_gpu, CV_BGR2GRAy)

Tags: opencv, gpu

I am trying to learn how to use the GPU programs in OpenCV. I have built everything with CUDA and if I run

```
cout << " Number of devices " << cv::gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() << endl;
```

I get the answer 1 device so at least something seems to work. However, I try the following peace of code, it just prints out the message and then nothing happens. It gets stuck on

```
cv::gpu::cvtColor(input_gpu, output_gpu, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main(void){
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread("image.jpg");

    if (input.empty()){
        cout << "Image Not Found" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cv::Mat output;

    // Declare the input and output GpuMat
    cv::gpu::GpuMat input_gpu;
    cv::gpu::GpuMat output_gpu;

    cout << "Number of devices: " << cv::gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() << endl;
    // Copy the input cv::Mat to device.
    // Device memory will be allocated automatically according to the parameters of input image
    input_gpu.upload(input);
    // Convert the input image to grayScale on GPU
    cv::gpu::cvtColor(input_gpu, output_gpu, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    //// Copy the result from GPU back to host

    output_gpu.download(output);

    cv::imshow("Input", input);
    cv::imshow("Output", output);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

I just found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823186/opencv-gpu-mat-hanging) issue and it seems to be a problem with the Maxwell architecture, but that post is over a year old. Has anybody else experienced the same problem? I am using windows 7, Visual Studio 2013 and an Nvidia Geforce GTX 770.

/ Erik

Comment: did you compile openCV with cuda support? please post std::cout << cv::getBuildInformation() << std::endl;

Comment: I compiled with build_gpu and with_CUDA. I can post the output tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I do not really know what the problem was, but in CMake, I changed the CUDA_GENERATION to Kepler, which is the micro architecture of my GPU, then I recompiled it, and now the code works as it should.

Interestingly, there were only Fermi and Kepler to choose, so I do not know if one will get problem with Maxwell.

/ Erik